# Why was my comment deleted?

Tags: discussion, comments, deleting

Yesterday I down-voted the answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343572/177954
because the websites where the images are from are not disclosed. I left a comment explaining this.

Today I noticed that my comment was deleted. Why is this? When I down-voted there was a pop-up that asked to leave a comment explaining the reason, that what I did.

Comment: The image in the now deleted answer seem, with great likelihood, screen shots. There's no need to give credit or cite sources for screen shots from one's own machine.

Comment: @egreg The screenshots are not from the machine of the OP, they were taken from another website. If one takes images from other websites, one needs to give credit to them!

Comment: @egreg Another example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412152/177954 does not disclose that the image is taken from http://wwwu.uni-klu.ac.at/magostin/img/cirkuit2.png Making other people (proved by your misunderstanding of the situation) believe that an image is one's own work, while it was created by others, is utterly wrong (and might even infringe the terms and conditions of using the image upload dialogue)

Comment: You're wrong. The site is cited and the image is seen in the linked page.

Comment: @egreg The site is cited in a general context, not as source of the image.

Comment: @egreg Also uploading an image with questionable permission rights to imgur is not right

Comment: This is hair-splitting. Anyway, I still consider that downvoting is inappropriate. Flag *and* leave a comment asking the poster to disclose the sources. This will make the poster aware of the situation.

Comment: @egreg No hair splitting, just respecting the work and effort of other people

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've had a few comments on that particular answer. Issues about 'legal' stuff are best handled by flagging rather than voting (a downvote indicates the answer is wrong on  a technical level, rather than having an attribution issue). After looking again, I've remove the answer entirely.

Comment: I would vote to you again If I could, I have seen you so much working towards this site, keep it up! Moderators like you are insanely difficult to find in Stack overflow or ell.SE....